# ALTER COLUMN Command doesn't work SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want to add to a primary key in one table a references to the primary key of another table.

my code:

```
 CREATE TABLE[payment]
 (ID int Primary key)

CREATE TABLE [tab]
(ID int Primary key references tab2(ID))

Alter Table payment
alter column ID
ADD constraint fk_payment
references tab(ID)
```

i get the error that the syntax near constraint is wrong, but i don't know what to change

because of the not changeable order of the table Alter table is the only option. to reference from one table to the other doesn't work cause I've references from that table to another one already.

i need two one-to-one-relations from one table to another

Comment: Normally, two primary keys would not reference each other.  Why not just put all the columns in a single table?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a FK constraint, just use this code:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.payment
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_payment
      FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES dbo.tab(ID)
```

You don't need to alter the column or table - just add the constraint

Comment: I need two one-to-one relations, so foreign key wouldn't work i think :(  so i need a primary key constraint

Comment: @noclue123: you **already have** the primary keys defined ...... when one table links to another, that's a **foreign key** constraint